# Why can I not activate ICC color profiles?

Tags: 16.04, colors, color-management

The color profiles in the list (Settings>color) look the same and seem not to get activated. Even the default 'Swapped Red and Green' looks the same, as well as the test profile I created in Windows 10 that was supposed to look extremely off. The default 'Blue' profile however does add a blue cast.

What I have tried, with no effect:

- Installing, uninstalling, reinstalling gnome-color-manager
- Removing Redshift

[Image of my Colors window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyt4w.png)

Answer (score 0):

The profiles are activated, but are only applied to images with color profiles. It requires a restart of color-managed applications, such as Digikam. Why this is the case and why the 'Blue' profile is applied system-wide is unclear to me.